# Select and show data 2 collection mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb

i have 2 collection 'campaigns' and 'landingpages'.

**campaigns**

```
——————————————————————————————
'campaign_id' |'campaign_name'
——————————————————————————————
     1        |  Campaign 1
     2        |  Campaign 2
```

**landingpages**

```
—————————————————————————————————
'campaign_id' |'landingpage_name'
—————————————————————————————————
     1        |  Landing 1
     2        |  Landing 2
```

I want to select and show data form 2 collection ( same join query in sql)

```
——————————————————————————————————
'landingpage_name'|'campaign_name'
——————————————————————————————————
    'Landing 1'   | 'Campaign1'
    'Landing 2'   | 'Campaign2'
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't do JOINs - period. When you need to correlate data from two different collections, you need to do the join on the application layer.

First query the first collection.

Then loop over the results and query the second collection with the result from the first query.

Comment: Thanks philipp. You are write example code here? If you use loop. if i want to select 10 collection and loop 10 collection ?. is it good for performance.

Answer (score 0):

As Philipp says, MongoDB doesn't do JOINs. [+info](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) You need to do the join on the application layer or iterate with javascript on the mongodb shell:

```
db.campaigns.find().forEach(

  function(doc){
    db.landingpages.find({campaign_id:doc.campaign_id},{landingpage_name:1}).forEach(

      function(doc2){  
        print(doc.campaign_id,doc.campaign_name,doc2.landingpage_name); 
      }

    )
  }

)
```

Comment: Thanks Gonzalez. But i code php. can you convert javascript to php ?